# How to replace text area code into html editor in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I can I edit the **Text Area Code** from text area into an HTML wysiwyg editor?  I know that in order to do that you need to convert it in this format. `<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() ); ?>` but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

**Text Area Code**

```
<label><?php echo $site_title; ?></label>      
<input name="<?php echo $name;?>" id="<?php echo $name;?>" <?php if($value){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?>  value="1" type="checkbox" /> 
<?php
} elseif($type=='textarea') {
?>
<label><?php echo $site_title; ?></label>
<textarea name="<?php echo $name;?>" id="<?php echo $name;?>"><?php echo $value;?>
</textarea>
```

after posting  this question I found out how it is implemented on my theme on other fields such as this:

```
<textarea  name="proprty_feature" id="proprty_feature" class="textarea" rows=""  cols=""  <?php if($property_feature_pkg==0){echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?> ><?php  if($property_feature_pkg==1){ echo esc_attr(stripslashes($proprty_feature));} ?></textarea> 
            <?php }else{ wp_editor( stripslashes($proprty_feature), 'proprty_feature', array( 'editor_class' => 'at-wysiwyg', 'media_buttons' => false ) );}?>
```

but still **cant figure out** how to change the text area code into similar format.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you find a plugin for that? If I'm interpreting your question right i think this plugin might do the job: https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE

Comment: actually im trying to fit in the text **area code** to a format like this `<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() ); ?>` in order to display the custom field in  wysiwyg editor.